# Parent component should be active when angular material dialog is open

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have implemented angular material dialog in my project , I also made the dialog draggable. Everything is working fine. Now I have a new requirement where I should keep parent component active when I open the dialog . Anyone have any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: can you try to add hasBackdrop:false to open method.

Comment: that works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any way we can only enable part of the page and disable other part of the page?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class to disable the particular part based on the dialog.

In your component, you can add a variable to identify the dialog state.

```
openDialog(): void {
this.dialogActive = true;
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
  hasBackdrop: false
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.dialogActive = false;
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  this.animal = result;
});
```

}
}

and you can add a class to HTML based on the dialog state.

```
<div [class.modal-page-disable]="dialogActive"> disable part </div>
<div> enable part </div>
```

Then finally add the style to disable the part.

```
.modal-page-disable {
   pointer-events: none;
   background: transparent;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

you can refer the sample code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gndo5h).

Comment: This helped , Thank you. But not sure why [class.modal-page-disable] is not working for my div . For me [class.disabled]="dialogActive"  and adding css 


.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events:none;
}
 resolved the issue